# Angular10: Getting blank values in database after form submitting

Tags: angular, angular10

I am working in angular project where i am trying to insert form data into my database through the user. For the database purpose i am using `microsoft sql server mamangment` All things are working fine. no errros are showing in vs code and console.

**The prolem is that after submiting the form Blank values are getting in my database only id is incrementing or you can see [here](https://ibb.co/XX3WZNF) what is happening**

**this is my source code on [github](https://github.com/neha0842/carepoint). you can check**

As i have found some similar questions but it didn't help me.

**care.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:53367/api/reports';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CareService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(baseUrl);
  }

  get(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  create(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }

  update(id, data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  deleteAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(baseUrl);
  }

  findByTitle(title): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${baseUrl}?title=${title}`);
  }
  

 

}
```

**report.comonent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CareService} from 'src/app/services/care.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  report = {
    name:'',
    email:'',
    date:'',
    age:'',
    mobile:'',
    result:'',
  };
  submitted = false;

  constructor(private careservice: CareService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  savereport(): void {
    const data = {
      name: this.report.name,
      email:this.report.email,
      date:this.report.date,
      age:this.report.age,
      mobile:this.report.mobile,
      result:this.report.result
    };

    this.careservice.create(data)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  newTutorial(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this. report = {
      name:'',
      email:'',
      date:'',
      age:'',
      mobile:'',
      result:'',
    };
  }

}
```

**report.comonent.html**

```
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <span style="font-size: 20px;" class="badge badge-info ">Create your Medical Report::</span>
            
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Name::</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="report.name"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Email::</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="email"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="report.email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">date::</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="date"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="report.date"
                name="date"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Age::</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="age"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="report.age"
                name="age"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="inputDefault">Mobile Number::</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="mobile"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="report.mobile"
                name="mobile"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleTextarea">Your Diagnoised Result::</label>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="result"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="report.result"
                name="result"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
              />
              </div>
            
              <button  (click)="savereport()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg ml-1">Reset</button>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

Please help,,...Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

This is your action method in your controller :

```
[ResponseType(typeof(report))]
public IHttpActionResult Postreport(report report)
```

And this is how you call that service in your client

```
create(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }
```

There is no method on your controller marked with a `HttpPost` attribute. So you are probably getting a 404 response. And you also need to modify your parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute For posting data you need to change your method into this :

```
[ResponseType(typeof(report))]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Postreport([FromBody]report report)
```

Also, need to mention that you need to do the same thing for other HTTP verbs (put, delete, etc.)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer ...actually i am new to this...can you tell me where i can find ```[ResponseType(typeof(report))]
public IHttpActionResult Postreport(report report)```

Comment: @Nehasingh in the repository you have posted : [this line](https://github.com/neha0842/carepoint/blob/6fa28610a8dd7d895ea768723dad3e672fe89297/carepoint/Controllers/reportsController.cs#L75)

Comment: I have change as you said. please check [here](https://ibb.co/fDGbB5n)...but still i am getting blank values...and aftre changing i have also build the program. but still......

Comment: still the same error....[done](https://ibb.co/RjbyJN8) as you have said